# How to make myself sleep on my side?

Tags: sleep, position, sleep-apnea

Following a sleep study, I've been diagnosed with *mild, positional obstructive sleep apnea*.

One of the clinic's recommendations is:

> The patient should **avoid sleeping supine** given non-supine [AHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apnea%E2%80%93hypopnea_index) is in the normal range.

In other words, I'm fine if I can manage to sleep on my side and avoid the tendency to sleep on my back.  But it's hard to control my unconscious body movements while I'm sleeping.

What are some good techniques to encourage side-sleeping?  (One solution would be to sleep sitting up, but I consider that to be a non-viable solution, since it impacts sleep quality in other ways.)

Comment: This is mostly anecdotal - a friend of mine said he affixed a tennis ball to his pajama at the center of his back; worked for him.

Comment: A good side sleeping pillow is important also to support your airways

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Aganju said, you can sew things into your pyjamas so you get uncomfortable when sleeping on your side.

There are belt products like SLUMBERBUMP that prevent you from rolling onto your back.

Another remedy that I've tried was to roll myself into a blanket with a lot of pillows on my back. This prevented my from rolling over at night